# Need help looping through cells in function

Tags: vba, excel

I want to loop through an entire column `W2`, while taking the average of each row. the column is 1326 long.

The code I have below only calculates the average of `W2` and `B2`. Can someone help

```
NumCellsFromEdge = 3
Dim NumOfCells As Integer
NumOfCells = 3

MsgBox GetTopDrTS(NumCellsFromEdge, NumOfCells) & " = average of " & NumCellsFromEdge & " cells in, and " & NumOfCells & " cells wide"

End Sub

Function GetTopDrTS(L_NumCellsFromEdge As Integer, L_NumOfCells As Integer) As Double
Dim val As Double
Dim mycol As Double
val = 0
mycol = 23

'Range("W2").Select
'Columns(mycol).Select

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To L_NumOfCells - 1
Range("W2" & i).Select

    val = val + Selection.Worksheet.Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column + EdgePos + L_NumCellsFromEdge + i).Value

Next i

GetTopDrTS = val / L_NumOfCells

End Function
```

Comment: What is `EdgePos` and where does it get its value?

Comment: Edgepos gets it values from row B23.

Comment: its cheks for the edge position on my xl spread sheet

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
MsgBox [average(w:w)]
```

Comment: At first reading I thought you wanted to average the values in the W column. Reading again I think you want something else. Can you clarify the goal?

Answer (score 0):

Application.average(sheets(1).range("E:E"))

will tell you the average of column E in sheets 1